# Sieve of Erastothenes

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

I'm solving some programming problems in euler project, and i stoped in this problem:

**generating the prime number**

I understood the algorithm but i didn't understood one thing in the solution :

Here is a solution i took from another discussion:

```
void sieve_of_eratosthenes(int n)
{
    bool *sieve = new bool[n+1];

// Initialize
sieve[0]=false;
sieve[1]=false;
sieve[2]=true;

for(int i=3;i<n+1;++i)
    sieve[i]=true;

// Actual sieve
for(int i=1; i<n+1; ++i)
    //**i didnt understood what is the purpose of this condition**
    if(sieve[i]==true)
        for(int j=2;j*i<n+1;++j)
            sieve[j*i]=false;

// Output
cout << "Prime numbers are: " <<endl;
for(int i=0;i<n+1;++i)
    if (sieve[i])
        cout << i <<endl;

delete [] sieve;
```

}

```
int main()
{
    int n = 70;
    sieve_of_eratosthenes(n);
}
```

i understood that in the condition we try to know if the number is prime or not , but i don't understood why we jump the not prime number

any help will be useful to me, thank you

Comment: This is how the sieve works. You start by assuming that all numbers are prime. Then, for each prime number (beginning from 2 and going up), you discard ("sift out", hence "sieve") all numbers that are multiples of it. So the condition, and the loop it protects, means this: "if `i` is prime, then mark all multiples of `i` as non-prime". Try it with pen and paper, up to, say, 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficiency. Lets look at the composite number 4. Do we really need to check all the other numbers for divisibility? No, because we already checked for its prime factors.

In short, checking composite numbers is a redundant process because we check its prime factors.

Comment: you are awesome like your pseudo , thank you and keep helping people

Answer (score 2):

A prime number is a number that has no divisors besides 1 and itself.

The aim of the sieve is to mark all multiples of the prime number as not being prime.
To do so we check if the number is prime, and mark all numbers that are a multiple of that prime as not prime.

To visualize this a bit. Let's say we start from number 2.

> Is 2 prime? Yes. 
>   Mark all 2*x where x < n. That would mark 2,4,6,8
>   etc.
>
> Is 3 prime? Yes. Mark all 3*x -> 3,6,9 etc.
>
> Is 4 prime? No. If we would not have this condition we would mark
>   4,8,16 etc as not prime, but we have already done this with 2.

Comment: thank you very much , it's the last sentense which explaine what i search